# Colours of the mesh are gone after I rendered and saved the project

Tags: modeling

I am new to blender so maybe this is something obvious, but I can't solve it:
When I saved my file, the colours were fine. As I opened it again, I could not see the colours anymore but at the menu they were still there.
Left some screenshots to make the problem clearer.
can anyone help me?? thanks so much
[image]

Comment: Hold Z and you'll get a pie menu for shading modes.

Answer (score 3):

You are in solid preview mode. Press <kbd>Z</kbd> in the 3D viewport and select either "Material Preview" or "Rendered" from the pie menu. You can also change preview modes by clicking on one of the 4 little circles in the top-right of the viewport (left to right - Wireframe, Solid, Material Preview, Rendered)

[image: Buttons]